# Texmaker is Not installing?

Tags: errors, installing, texmaker

I am getting Error while installing Texmaker in ubantu 14.04. Error is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package texmaker_ubuntu_14.04_4.5_i386
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'texmaker_ubuntu_14.04_4.5_i386'
```

What is a Problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install texstudio
```

These two packages are essentially the same... You do not even need to download the `.deb` file manually if you are installing from Ubuntu repositories.

Should you (for some reason) want `texmaker` instead of `texstudio`, just replace the last word of the command. (The `texstudio` package seems to be more frequently updated in Ubuntu: the latest version of `texstudio` is 2.11, the repos contain 2.10.8—2.11 as of today, whereas the latest version of `texmaker` is 4.5, dated October 2015, and the repos contain 4.3, which is even older.)